# My server freezes after update apache2 server

Tags: server, lamp, restore

I have a ubuntu server 12.04 with LAMP and ubuntu desktop enviroment. I updated the server and after a reboot it froze and now I can't even access the tty's 1...6.
Before the update, the server was hosting my webpage.

How can I restore my server without loosing all the info?

Answer (score 0):

Do you host your server at home or in DC? If at home try to load from livecd and read logs or load in recovery mode from grub and try to do the same. (/var/log/syslog and etc)